# Sequence splitting

Tags: code-golf, string

Given an arbitrary sequence consisting of 1 and A
split this sequence up so that A is at the beginning of each sub sequence.
Sequences without a leading A and Sequences without 1 before the next A will be self contained.

Example

Input

```
111A11A1111111A1A1AA
```

should result in

```
111
A11
A1111111
A1
A1
A
A
```

Above already contains the edge cases
* sequence of 1 without prior A
* subsequent A's without 1 between

*Update*
Open to all programming languages (functional / non-functional)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. You'd need to add a winning criterion such as `code-golf`. Also, it might be a dupe -- but I didn't check yet. For future submissions, you may want to use [our sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before posting to the main site.

Comment: You should add more examples with some edge cases, as currently looks like a simple `s/A/\nA/g` task.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Iam not sure if my question is best placed here now. I was really looking into results in scala and other similar programming languages. I will take this elsewhere i guess.

Comment: If you update your question to fit our criteria, I'll happily post answers in Scala and Standard ML!

Comment: `s/question/challenge/`

Comment: (... yes, we don't do Q&A here, sorry)

Comment: "This **question** appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:

'**Questions** without an objective primary winning criterion...'
If this **question** can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the **question**."

Comment: Can we use `a` instead of `A`?

Comment: I've voted to close this challenge as "without a winning criteria" because you need to [explicitly state the winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13090/does-the-op-have-to-explicitly-state-the-winning-criteria/13091#13091).

Comment: I think this challenge is too simple.

Comment: Is a trailing newline allowed?

Comment: Please add an example that starts with an **A**. The behavior of the current answers is *very* inconsistent for everything except the one example you provide.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Anonymous tacit function. Returns a list of strings.

```apl
⊢⊂⍨1⊣@1=∘'A'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYsedTU96l1h@KhrsYOh7aOOGeqO6v//P2qbmKagbmho6AhGYOAIgo7qAA) (`↑` is just to display the list of strings as separate lines.)

`=∘'A'` Boolean list (1s and 0s) indicating As

`1⊣@1` replace with a 1 at the first position

`⊢⊂⍨` begin partitions of the argument at each 1 in that

Comment: Hmm, I never programmed in APL, so perhaps it's not possible/shorter, but isn't there a simple replace every `A` with `\nA`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Then it is time to [begin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard)! Dyalog APL [has PCRE](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wR1DT1NR/VHfVOD1GMMY/KAzN7FjzoXAiUV1A0NDR3BCAwcQdBRHQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") built-in, but it isn't so simple. See the discussion beginning [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43962717#43962717).

Comment: 10 bytes: `'.1*'⎕s'&'`

Comment: @ngn There's no way you're telling me that that is a derivative of mine. Go ahead and post it or the equivalent 5-byter QuadS.

Comment: @Adám Of course, it isn't. Unfortunately it's on hold now and I can't post [the 5-byter](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn@/1/PUItL7f9/Q0NDRzACA0cQdAQA).

Comment: @ngn Not on hold any more.

Comment: @Adám really? I still see it as on hold

Comment: @ngn Oh, it was off hold, now on hold again. ⍨

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!*

```
L`.1*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3ydBz1Dr/39DQ0NHMAIDRxB0BAA)

#### Explanation

```
L`      Configure the stage as "list", so that it outputs all matchings
.1*     Regex to be matched: any character followed by zero or more "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 6 bytes

```
\BA
¶A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P8bJkevQNsf//w0NDR3BCAwcQdARAA)

An alternative to Luis's solution. Finds all `A` which are preceded by another character and inserts a linefeed in front of them.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>54</s> 37 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
groupBy(\_ x->x<'A')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrzTa9KL@0wKlSIyZeoULXrsJG3VFd839uYmaegq1CQWlJcEmRXnFGfrmCikKagpKhoaEjGIGBIwg6Kv0HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
'A"
A".:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f3VGJy1FJz@r/f0NDQ0cwAgNHEHQEAA)

Can probably be golfed further, but first submission and attempt at this.

**Explanation**

```
'A"           Push A character, Push string "(new line) A"
 A"           close string
.:            Replace all. Replace "A" with "(new line) A" in input
```

<s>If you want code to match output like in original post then 11 bytes</s>

```
I'A" A".:#»
```

-2 bytes thanks to Soaku!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [You can save 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f3VGJy1FJz@r/f0NDQ0cwAgNHEHQEAA) (never used 05AB1E, but works)

Comment: [You can save another](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f3fFRwzwuRz2r//8NDQ0dwQgMHEHQEQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
#@~:d%5/ja,,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X9mhzipF1VQ/K1FH5/9/Q0NDRzACA0cQdAQA)

```
#@            # skips @
  ~           push a byte of input
   :          duplicate it
    d%        modulo 13, 'A':0, '1':10
      5/      divided by 5, 'A':0, '1':2
        j     jump this number of blocks, skips the next two instructions for '1'
         a,   push 10 to the stack and output as a byte (\n)
           ,  output the byte of input
```

If there is no input left, `~` reflects the pointer and `@` terminates the program

Comment: Alternatively, `#@~:9%j  a,,` and `#@~:5%ja,  ,`. The last one could be 10 bytes, but it outputs an extra null byte

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

1 The slooooow but shorter method which gets all ways* to partition the list and then finds the maximal as measured by its transpose:

```
ŒṖZÞṪ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p0Udnvdw56r/h9sj//9XMjQ0dAQjMHAEQUclAA)**

* that is all **2<sup>length(input)-1</sup>** ways!

2 The speedy method using the "partition at truthy indices" atom (the five byte `=”Aœṗ` fails for inputs starting with `A`):

```
Ḋ=”A0;œṗ
```

**[Try the speedy one!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hji7bRw1zHQ2sj05@uHP6/8Ptkf//KxkaGjqCERg4gqCjEgA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
d'A_iR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P0XdMT4z6P9/JUNDQ0cwAgNHEHRUAgA)

#### Explanation:

```
d'A_iR
d       // Replace:
 'A     //   "A" with
   _iR  //   newline + "A"
```

Alternative 6-byte solution

```
r'A"
A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v0jdUYnL8f9/JUNDQ0cwAgNHEHRUAgA)

These would be 5-byte solutions if we could take `a` instead of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 40 bytes

```ml
String.translate(fn#"A"=>"\nA"|x=>str x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq7CoAwDAB/JcTFDgqdpYV8g6tLBytCTKUN0sF/r4@7G68cPBysSdoVGCI4aLPmXbZRc5DCQdc@SoeEzuMihHd1vmiGatoE/fmuCgmiAbTW0t8PfRJO7QE)

Unfortunate that `String.translate` is so long...

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 8 bytes

```perl
s/A/
A/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79Y31Gfy1E//f9/Q0NDRzACA0cQdPyXX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 27 bytes

```javascript
z=>z.split(/(?=A)/).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcJBDsAQEEDRfS/CLEocQBs3IUpDxEhJFy4/Tf33s3td909qY694BYqapj6m6K2kwSU/tQEJImOqdrPksXYsQRS8eeRMKWXWK/MzDIA@)

---

## Explanation :

```javascript
z =>                   // lambda function taking z as input
    z.split(           // convert z to an array by splitting at
            /(?=A)/    // all `A's`
    ).                 // end split
        join`\n`       // join all via new line
```

---

## Alternate :

If printing an array is okay, then :

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 19 bytes

```javascript
z=>z.split(/(?=A)/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/K1q5Kr7ggJ7NEQ1/D3tZRU1/zf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGuqGhoSMYgYEjCDqqa2r@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.match(/A1*|^1+/g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5RCoMwDP33FJkMbDen9AAVeg5x6DS6irOydmPgPHtXdYyZhJeXPB5JWzwLXd7lYE69qtDW3Gqe6OhWmPJKYsEO7zM7xg21BrXhRPZDiK@B8mT0AGRN6nlFo1bJPs933GlfTp0OUKpeqw6jTjUkb5SBdD@ulimDy8OAM2BpsJoFx6dsMWKncePdnOGbM5M3v0Z8xphYagkxp/DDFAI3BSEE4teWWPkfrgAZ9ewH)

Comment: Not sure if this would pass a different test case, but the regex `/[A1]1*/g` is reduces this by one byte (and passes the provided test case).

Comment: Why not `.1*`??

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```scala
_.replace("A","\nA")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUK1QlpijkGalEFxSlJmXrmBrB2f9j9crSi3ISUxO1VByVNJRislzVNL8XwCULMnJ00jTUDI0NHQEIzBwBEGgCk0urtr/AA)

(Not sure if putting the types in the header is allowed, I'll change it if not.)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split(/(?=A)/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5Yr7ggJ7NEQ1/D3tZRU1/zf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGkqGhoSMYgYEjCDoqaWoq6OtHK6gDRdR1FNQd4RQYQNhIJIRQiOX6DwA)

Thanks Pandacoder for 1 byte

Comment: It doesn't say outputting a list of lines is acceptable, so this answer is currently invalid.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Requirement says "split this sequence up", not "split with newline"

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing*

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/A/g,`
A`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5Yryi1ICcxOVVD31E/XSeByzFB839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahpKhoaEjGIGBIwg6Kmlqcv0HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
:Q\A"
A
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3AQ%5CA%22%0AA&input=%22111A11A1111111A1A1AA%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
:Q\A"\nA
:Q         Replace in the input...
  \A       ... every instance of "A"...
    "\nA   ... with a newline followed by "A".
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda I:I.replace('A','\nA')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUcHTylOvKLUgJzE5VUPdUV1HPSbPUV3zf0FRZl6JQpqGuqGhoSMYgYEjCILkAQ)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 44 bytes

```
@set/pa=
@for %%a in (%a:A= A%)do @echo %%a
```

Takes input on STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 19 bytes

```java
s->s.split("(?=A)")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoMwDIbvPkXw1MIseN509LLbTh7HDp1Oqau1mCjI8Nk7rRtLAn8g@b5WTSppq5cvjUKEq9IW3hGAGx9Gl4CkaI2p1xV0640VNGjb3O6ghgZ5eAVoV4kYSRtRj7Yk3Vtx@S6nHTj8uBzqzGOSo0BnNLGYnTPJY@6PwVTMSM9O9CMJtwJkLPvL5TCoGQX1u4zVQjlnZhanaSrDhJJby5hzvjmXaPEf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 59 bytes

```
rEEeREeEeeeeeEREeeeeeeeeREEreeEREEeeREEreEeREEeEReEREEeeRee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#zeZnsZlxZ7z9ZsZ7zaZtZ5ZsZ4)

That was hard... Outputs with leading newline.

```
rEEe           # r - Get input               Take the string

REeEeeeeeE     # R - Push A                  A - splitter
REeeeeeeee     # R - Push \0                 \0 - end
REE            # R - Create label A          label A: Next + newline

 reeE          # Output newline              Output newline

 REEee         # R - Forward                 
 REE           # R - Create label \0         label \0: Next without newline

 reEe          # r - Output                  Output the current letter and pop it

 REEeE         # R - Rewind                  
 ReE           # r pointer == A, goto A      Output newline, next letter

 REEee         # R - Forward                 Else
 Ree           # r pointer != \0, goto \0    If stack isn't empty, next letter
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
f s=do c<-s;['\n'|c>'1']++[c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2DYlXyHZRrfYOlo9Jk@9JtlO3VA9Vls7Ojn2f25iZp6CrUJmXklqUWJyiULaf0NDQ0cwAgNHEHQEAA)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 26 bytes

Not a whole lot to explain with this one.

```
cat(gsub("A","\nA",scan()))
```

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 9 bytes

```
s/A/\nA/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1jfUT8mz1E//f9/Q0NDRzACA0cQdAQA)

Comment: sed is a language on its own, so you only have to count the bytes in the actual sed command.

Comment: As nothing else is matched beside group 1, you may skip the capturing: `s/1*/&\n/g`.

Comment: With Awk you could benefit of defaults: by default `gsub()` operates on `$0`; the default action is `print`; by default `print` also operates on `$0`: `gsub("A","\nA")1`.